# What is a simple calculation to figure out how many watts needed to maintain a hot piece of tungsten?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, estimation, metals

The specific heat of tungsten is [$.13 (\text{kJ /(kg K)})$](https://www.google.com/search?q=specific%20heat%20of%20tungsten&oq=speci&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i65l3j0.2056j1j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

[1 cubic cm of tungsten is .0193 kg](http://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-to-weight)

And the melting point of stainless steel is $1900 \deg \text{K}$ conservatively (giving it plenty of heat in the liquid state).

So I calculate $.13 \times .0193 \times 1900 \approx 4.8 \text{k J}$.

So how many watts of energy input into a system of tungsten that touches only air and ceramic alumina do I need to maintain $4.8 \text {k J}$ in a steady state?

I'm not sure how much heat gets dissipated.

I'm hoping to maintain it with a $1000 \text{W}$ induction heater, assuming 100% efficiency.

In your answer feel free to use formulas / more abstract-looking math.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you're trying to do. Are you trying to maintain tungsten at a temperature of $1900 K$? Why is the metling point of steel involved in this calculation?

Comment: In free air, or in vacuum?  You need the area.  You will have loses due to convection (if in air) and through radiation (for both.)  Convection will be hard to estimate,  radiation is a bit easier.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation#Radiative_heat_transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, there is no way to determine what you're asking. Apparently you want to heat 1 cc of tungsten to the melting point of stainless steel using an induction heater. If you do this, you will have to apply a net energy of $4.8 kJ$, as you have calculated. Apparently the tungsten will be supported on an alumina surface or in an alumina crucible. And then you want to maintain the tungsten at that temperature.

First, stainless will melt in a range of [1325 to 1530 C](http://www.bssa.org.uk/topics.php?article=103), or 1600 to 1800 K, so I don't know where you got 1900 K from.

At 1900 k the tungsten will radiate as a black body per the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) but you have not specified the area of tungsten not in contact with the alumina. A sphere will radiate a good deal less power (and take less power to maintain its temperature) than a large thin disk of the same mass.

Similarly, the alumina will radiate but in a constrained way. If you know the radiating area of the alumina and its thickness, you can use its thermal conductivity to determine the outer temperature when the outer surface is radiating. This will be complicated by  the fact that the emissivity of alumina is not 1, and does not vary with temperature in a nice way. At any rate, the thermal conductivity of the alumina will depend on its dimensions and geometry, which you have not provided.

Finally, your sample/support combination will also lose heat to convection and conduction, both of which are, again, dependent on dimensions and geometry.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to maintain something at a particular temperature, you don't really care about the heat capacity of the material.  Instead you need to calculate the heat loss and the power needed to replace it.  It sounds to me like you don't care so much about maintaining the heat in the tungsten as maintaining the heat in the steel.

> I'm not sure how much heat gets dissipated.

Unfortunately, that part is critical.  You can calculate how much power is necessary to maintain a certain area of material at a certain temperature if most of the heat loss is through black-body radiation (See [Stefan-Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).  But that would be a very inefficient oven.

To keep high temps, you really want excellent insulation.  When the heat loss is low, then the power to maintain the temperature is also very low.

---

If you want to assume no insulation then here's how it would work.

At very high temperatures, most of the heat loss will be through radiation.  If we can assume it to be a black-body radiator, then we can use [Stefan-Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).

$$P = A \epsilon \sigma T^4$$

For a good radiator, $\epsilon$ will tend to 1.  Metals aren't that good though.  [Engineering toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/emissivity-coefficients-d_447.html) suggests that tungsten will be somewhere between $0.3$ and $0.03$.

The bigger the objects surface area, the more it radiates.  So you need more energy to keep a tiny object hot than to keep a large one hot.

So if we assume you had a straight wire that was $1\text{mm}$ in diameter and $1\text{cm}$ long, it would have a surface area of $3.1 \times 10^{-5}\text{m}^2$.  I'll further assume $\epsilon = 0.2$ and use $\sigma = 5.67 \times 10^{-8} \text{W m}^{-2} \text{K}^{-4}$.

Plug it all in and you get the power to maintain it at $1900\text{K}$ is about $5\text{W}$.  As it gets bigger, the heat losses increase and you need more power.

Comment: You also need to deal with convection and conduction.