# How quickly does a small piece of molten steel cool at room temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, metals, experimental-technology, technology

Say I have a $(\frac{1}{2}D)^2 \pi \times \ell = (.05)^2 \pi \times .03 \approx 0.000236  \ \text{mm}^3$ piece of molten steel freshly spewed out of a hot nozzle.  Now assuming the nozzle moves away quickly enough (because it's hot and radiates heat at close range by convection and radiation), how quickly will the piece of steel solidify?  How do I calculate *that*?

Comment: I suggest having a look at this, for radiative losses: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211459/

Comment: Gert's link is a good start. Once you figure out how quickly energy is leaving the piece you can calculate how long it will take the steel to drop below its melting temperature using the heat capacity of steel.

Comment: @Gert but how do I find out how much internal heat energy a hot piece of steel has?  I need that in order to use $Q/(m \Delta T)$.

Comment: You will need the heat capacity (which is in general a function of temperature and material).

Comment: @DrXorile I already have heat capacity and it requires a change in temperature.  But the temperature is not changing, it's a constant melting point temp (until it starts to cool), so I don't know what you mean by "using heat capacity" to get $Q$.  Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always there are three sources of heat transfer.  Radiative, Conduction and Convection.

Radiative cooling will be a function of the emissivity ($\epsilon$ - look [here](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/emissivity-coefficients-d_447.html) - you can probably assume some oxidation, so close to 0.79), the surface area (probably roughly spherical if it's molten, but you can work it out from the geometry), and the temperature (it's also receiving radiation from the surroundings, and the temperature is changing, so it's a dynamic situation that trends exponentially towards room temperature.

However, what else is going on?  If it's flying through a vacuum, the above will be fine.  If not, you'll need heat transfer co-efficients.  If it lands on Cu it will cool much faster than if is lands on Alumina.  The thermal conductivity and size and temperature of the objects it interacts with will all be relevant.

If it's moving through the air, it will be different from if it's levitating in the air.

---

**Edit based on comments**

Presumably you're trying to make a 3D metal printer or something similar.  In this scenario almost all of the cooling is going to come from the substrate on which the droplet lands.  The wetting angle etc will also be relevant, because this effects the contact area.  This is not just blah blah.  If it balls up on the substrate it will cool *much* slower than if it wets the substrate and as a very fine angle.

So, let's start with the surface area.  Assume that you have a wetting angle of $\theta$.  Also assume that you form a droplet that is a [spherical cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html).  Then you know that the volume of the spherical cap is 
\begin{equation} V = \frac{1}{3}\pi R^3(2-3\cos\theta+\cos^3\theta) \end{equation}

The area is:
\begin{equation}A = \pi R^2\sin^2\theta\end{equation}
You know the volume ($V$) of your piece, so solve for $R$ using the first equation, and then calculate your contact area ($A$) using the second.

For a small droplet like that, I think you can assume that it is uniform temperature, so now you need to know how the heat is flowing.  One challenge is that the little volume where it lands will heat up, slowing the dissipation.  This is especially true if you have multiple droplets landing in a row.

However, let's assume that the substrate is a good enough conductor and is big enough that we can treat it like a heat sink with temperature $T_{\mathrm{sub}}\approx300\mathrm{K}$.

The molten droplet has temperature $T(t)$, where $t$ is time, and 0 is the moment it settles onto the substrate.

Now we need to work out how much heat energy there is and how to convert between energy (Joules) and temperature (Kelvin) for your little droplet.  This is heat capacity.  For solid steel it's about 0.46J.g$^{-1}$K$^{-1}$ (from wikipedia), and for molten steel it's about 0.82 (at least that's for Iron from [here](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/liquid-metal-boiling-points-specific-heat-d_1893.html)).  You can figure out your mass using the density of steel and the volume you gave.  That will give you a number in J/K (joules per kelvin) - call this number $c$.

Next take the heat transfer coefficient ($h$).  This all gives you:
\begin{equation} \frac{dT}{dt} = h\cdot A\cdot(T - T_{\mathrm{sub}})/c \end{equation}

which can be solved in the usual way to give you $T$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: Dude, I'm looking for a simple approximation, using the most significant sources of heat transfer, therefore I cannot accept your answer as is.

Comment: Then can you tell us more about your set-up?  What happens to the molten metal after it leaves the nozzle?

Comment: Please make the temperature coefficient of the surface it lands on a variable.  And also for a few fractions of a second it's very close to a large flat-faced object of the same temperature (melting point), then the print head moves away and it's left to cool at hopefully human temperatures.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Dr Xorile's considerations are correct - you can't get a estimate without the convective/conductive cooling effects.

Comment: Is the heat transfer coefficient of the substrate material or the droplet?

Comment: So we don't have to include radiative transfer?  And if so, do we count radiation into the substrate or just into the open air space?

Comment: Both! It's a function of both materials. Welcome to the messy world of material science!

Comment: You could include the radiation into air, but I would be willing to bet that the conduction into the substrate is at least an order of magnitude bigger, so you could just ignore it

Comment: What subject of book do you recommend if I wanted to solve more problems like these?  Heat transfer?  Materials Science?  Themodynamics?

Comment: Computational Fluid Dynamics would be a good place to start. You can model systems like yours and see what happens!